# Build failure app:checklDebugDuplicateClasses

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, recompile

I am trying to make a Google map API based activity that will show current location.

I also have tons of code and I couldn't find the problem.

I am getting the error on build output:

> https://pastebin.com/WhfLu1uS

Code:

```
 public class map extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
    {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

DatabaseReference drivers;
GeoFire geoFire;

Marker mCurrent;

MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Init view

    location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {

            if(isOnline){
                startLocationUpdates();
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You're Online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }else{
                stopLocationUpdates();
                mCurrent.remove();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You're Offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

    setUpLocation();

}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(checkPlayServices()){
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();
                        if(location_switch.isChecked())
                            displayLocation();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocation() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //req runtime permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{

                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            }else{
            if (checkPlayServices()){

                buildGoogleApiClient();
                createLocationRequest();
                if(location_switch.isChecked())
                    displayLocation();

            }
        }

    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST).show();
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        return false;

        }
        return true;

    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLastLocation != null){
            if(location_switch.isChecked()){
                final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                //update to firebase
                geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude),
                new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        // Add marker
                        if(mCurrent != null)
                            mCurrent.remove();//remove current marker
                        mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                                                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                                    .title("You"));

                        // move cam to pos
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15.0f));
                        // draw  animation
                        rotateMarker(mCurrent, -360, mMap);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("ERROR", "Cannot Get Your Location");
        }
    }

    private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
        final long duration = 1500;

        final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
                float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;
                mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);
                if(t<1.0){
                    handler.postDelayed(this,16);
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                         ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }


    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;




}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

I suddenly got this error when I saw a video on youtube that explains the code.

I am looking to solve this problem but don't know what cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below step make sure you don't have same library multiple times.

build.gradle

```
 //Google play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <application

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

activity_map.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MapActivity with runtime permission

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
        getDeviceLocation();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

    }
}

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

//vars
private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    getLocationPermission();
}

private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}

private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
    Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
}

private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            initMap();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                //initialize our map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Above code is how to load current loction in map also try this for your error.

1.close Android Studio (or IntelliJ IDEA)
2.in your project's directory:
   1.delete .idea directory
   2.delete .gradle directory
   3.delete all .iml files

3.use Android Studio to re-open the directory as a project

Comment: I fixed it but it appears to have another problem, when I open this specific activity, the app crashes because:   ZZZ Binary XML file line #24 in com.example.user.alphaver:layout/activity_map: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch ZZZ
I have done the implementation and I re-checked everything is fine, the drawable files exist but it still doesn't work.

Comment: its the different problem but hope my question has helped you you can ask different question for that also accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: also post you map activity which causing this issue?